# Hazelcast SqlPredicate on Date object

Tags: sql, date, hazelcast

i'm trying to build a SqlPredicate with Hazelcast that should filter by a date.

The exception i get is the following:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to parse date from value: '2013-06-21 03:15:44.000' ! 
Valid formats are: 'EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS' and 'yyyy-mm-dd'.
```

The strange thing is that my date exacly match the second "valid" pattern.

What should i do?
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm looking at the hazelcast source code, version 2.5, in package `com.hazelcast.query`, and it seems that date-related expressions used in a `Predicate` need to be in the format according to their type:

1. java.util.Timestamp - `"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS"`
2. java.sql.Date - `"yyyy-mm-dd"`
3. java.util.Date - `"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy"`

If you could easily use `java.util.Timestamp`, you can use the date expression in the format you have it.

Alternatively if you are using `java.util.Date` then can you try the same date in the format `"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy"`?

Hope this helps.

Relevant hazelcast source code from Predicates.java pasted below:

```
        } else if (type instanceof Timestamp) {
            if (value instanceof Date) { // one of java.util.Date or java.sql.Date
                result = value;
            } else {
                result = DateHelper.parseTimeStamp(valueString);
            }
        } else if (type instanceof java.sql.Date) {
            if (value instanceof Date) { // one of java.util.Date or java.sql.Timestamp
                result = value;
            } else {
                result = DateHelper.parseSqlDate(valueString);
            }
        } else if (type instanceof Date) {
            if (value instanceof Date) { // one of java.sql.Date or java.sql.Timestamp
                result = value;
            } else {
                result = DateHelper.parseDate(valueString);
            }
```

And from DateHelper.java

```
static final String timestampFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS";
static final String dateFormat = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy";
static final String sqlDateFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd";
```

Comment: Excellent! The too generic exception message confused me.

Comment: My edit to this answer was, I believe, rejected by mistake. But I would still like to point out that there is no `java.util.Timestamp` available in Java. @vikingsteve please change the references to the  `java.sql.Timestamp` instead. Thanks.